# bookdown! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \passthrough

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown, listings

I find that when use `pandoc --listings`, to render code chunk with latex listings package, it will change character, as [github](https://github.com/openframeworks/ofBook/issues/69) says, it is a bug. So pandoc had introduced `\passthrough` to process it.

I decide to update my pandoc to 2.2.1 version, the newest current. But it pops error like this,

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \passthrough
```

I thought it may be because of `listings` package too old without `\passthrough`. so I update to texlive 2018. it still had this problem. I submit this problem in https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/591

I had searched some result as,

- https://github.com/laboon/ebook/issues/139
- https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/591

but none can solve. Any suggestion? Thank you.

I think I should add  this command  by myself. texupdate too slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is not relevant to your LaTeX distribution, so there is no need to reinstall or update LaTeX.

Pandoc 2.x puts verbatim text in `\passthrough{}` defined at
https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/052428151/default.latex#L169
if the `--listings` flag is used in the command line.

```
$ echo '`text`' | pandoc -f markdown -t latex --listings
\passthrough{\lstinline!text!}
```

A few possible solutions (from the easiest to hardest):

- Set the option `template` to `null` in `bookdown::pdf_book`, i.e.,

  ```
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    template: null
  ```

  This means using Pandoc's built-in Pandoc template, which has defined `\passthrough`.
- Install the development version of **rmarkdown**: `devtools::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')`, in which I have [added the command](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/bc2a49ed9da00fd5ec414bc192b112bbba34513d).
- Define the command `\passthrough` in a custom Pandoc LaTeX template (https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/templates.html), and use the custom template via the `template` option of `bookdown::pdf_book()`.

Comment: Thank you. total code can watch https://github.com/bubifengyun/SJTUThesis-Rmd/blob/master/tex/template.tex?#L46#L50